# ASP.NET MVC: why is this code within my view displaying "<br>" rather than a line break?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have some code in my view which displays an employee's info (name, address, etc), within a grid. I'm having a problem however, when an employee's "Address 2" has data. In this circumstance, I need to place the Address 2 on a new line, within the same grid cell as Address 1.

So it should display as follows:

| Name | Address |
| --- | --- |
| John Smith | 123 My St |
| Amy Andrews | 456 Main St Apt B. |

Instead however, my Address 2 is displaying the following, which physically displays the "br" tag:

```
456 Main St<br>Apt B.
```

Here's my code, which basically says, display "AddressLine1" and IF "AddressLine2" is not null, then include a line break, followed by AddressLine2.

I know I can get this to work by breaking out the AddressLine1 & AddressLine2 segments & I'm not against it, but I'd prefer to keep it similar to the code that already exists, which is written similar to the following, if possible:

```
@if (member.Employee != null)
 {
      <td>
            @(member.Employee.FullName != null ? member.Employee.FullName : "-" )
      </td>
      <td>
            @(member.Employee.AddressLine1 != null ? member.Employee.AddressLine1 +
                                    (member.Employee.AddressLine2 != null ? "<br/>" +  
                                    member.Employee.AddressLine2 : "")
                                    : "-" )
      </td>
      ...
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Feels like the result is being escaped. I'd be willing to bet that `&lt;br/&gt;` is actually being rendered to the page to prevent potential XSS attacks or malicious code injection.

Comment: Your code doesn't emit the tag `<br/>` but a string that contains `<br/>`. Add an `@if` block to emit both the `<br/>` tag and the second address line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code doesn't emit the tag `<br/>` but a string that contains `"<br/>"`. Use an `@if` block to emit the data you want instead, the same way you did for `member.Employee` :

```
<td>
</td>
     @(member.Employee.FullName ?? "-" )
<td>
    @(member.Employee.AddressLine1 ?? "-")
    @if(member.Employee.AddressLine2 != null)
    {
       <br/>
       @(member.Employee.AddressLine2)
    }
</td>
```

Comment: Thanks!  Yeah, I was hoping to keep it all contained (address1 & address2) within the same block of code but after reading yours and others comments, I understand now why that won't work.  I went with your approach.
Thanks again for the help!